# SQL select is not picking other column's value in the same row as the aggregated row

Tags: mysql, sql

Examples speak most loudly:

```
select date from prices 
where (Close-Open)/Open = 
     (select max((Close-Open)/Open) as daychange from prices);
```

will give me the correct result:

```
2008-09-17
```

But

```
select max((close-open)/open) as daychange, date from prices;
```

will give me:

```
0.1082868629230968  | 2014-08-27
```

which is clearly not what I want.

Any better or cleaner way to do this query? I want to get the day with the most price change (in percentage).

Comment: You didn't use `GROUP BY` on `Date` column, so it takes first value of date. So, your first approach is right, you can only change your `WHERE` clause on `JOIN`.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL user, but I am surprised... MySQL does not throw error if you include both an aggregate function and an ordinary column reference in a select without specifying an appropriate group by?  It just pulls the data values for the non-aggregated expressions from the first row it finds?

Comment: `select max((close-open)/open) as daychange, date from prices;` will be rejected by all other DBMS due to the incorrect usage of aggregates. MySQL returns random (they call it "indeterminate") data instead. For details see here: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an aggregate function `max` with out providing a grouping criteria so your table prices will be treated as one group and the results of query will be returned in indeterminate  order means it will give you the max value for your criteria but it will not guarantee you to  give the relevant date which has the max value so your second query can be written as

```
select 
((close-open)/open) as daychange,
 date 
from prices
order by daychange desc
limit 1
;
```

So the above query will calculate daychange for each row and it will sort the result by daychange values in descending order and limiting to 1 will give you the max value for your criteria and the relevant data value too